# How to filter for nearby geometries

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, geospatial

I want to create a subset of census data for nearby political boundaries. For example, with zip code 17954, how do I filter a data frame containing all zip codes in the US to just zip codes within a 10 mile radius?

I would be using `tigris`, `dyplr` I believe for this. From [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfnetworks/vignettes/sfn03_join_filter.html) it seems I should use the `st_filter()` command to do so.

```
states = c(unique(FoodAccessResearchAtlasData2019$State))

state_list = vector("list", length = length(states))
for (i in 1:length(states)){
#tigris command cd=TRUE doesn't seem to work with year command, so this function suffices that
  dat = zctas(state = states[i], year = 2010)
  state_list[[i]] = dat
}
#combining into one large zip code data frame
zipcodes =  do.call(rbind, state_list)


nearby_zips = zipcodes %>%
  st_filter(zipcodes$ZCTA5CE10[17603], #this is what I imagine is the point to filter from
 ..predicate = st_is_within_distance,  #honestly just copying from the documentation
 dist = 10)                            #is within 10 miles, I don't know the base unit for the dist command
```

Comment: Can you give us some more details about what you're working with? Is `zipcodes` a spatial object (e.g., an object of class `sf` with a geometry column containing a polygon of the state)?

Comment: There is a zipcodeR package that could help here.

Comment: @StewartMacdonald yes, using the `zctas` from tigris contains many variables: `geometry`, and lat long coordinates which are the only ones I feel are important. the other pertain to area of water and land and names

Comment: @Dave2e i'll try that package it seems to solve what I want, just not how I want it